# getLastKnownLocation in a background service permission

Tags: android, service, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm trying to recover the last known position of the device inside a service started by an `BroadcastReceiver` triggered by the `AlarmManager` but i'm getting trouble with the permission management system, because even if i ask for the permission dynamically in the UI, i keep getting the log message `"Notification not allowed"`.

The goal of the `AlarmManager`/`BroadcastReceiver` combination is to perform a periodic call to a REST API which is determined by the user location.

#### Service code

The `onHandleIntent` method of the service is called by a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` with `startWakefulService`

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Handling intent");

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancelAll();

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setSpeedRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);

    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    boolean localizationPermitted = ContextCompact.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

    if (localizationPermitted) {
        Location lastLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Location: " +lastLocation.toString() );

        // stuff that needs the location

    } else {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.e(TAG, "Localization not allowed");
    }
}
```

#### Manifest Permissions

I've declared the permissions in the `AndroidMainfest.xml` file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ...">
    ...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    ...
</manifest>
```

#### Dynamic permission

I ask for the permission inside a `Fragment` of the application, before starting the alarm which triggers the service:

```
boolean gotPermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;


if (gotPermission){
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Got the permission");
    // Schedule the alarm
} else {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
}
```

and in the dialog's callback i got the `"Permission granted"`:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (permissions.length == 1 &&
            permissions[0].equals(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) &&
            grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Permission granted");
        }
    } else {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.e(TAG, "Permission not granted");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: @CommonsWare `targetSdkVersion` 25, `minSdkVersion` 19, `compileSdkVersion` 25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boolean localizationPermitted = ContextCompact.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
```

This will be `true` if the permission is *not* granted (`!=`). Change this to:

```
boolean localizationPermitted = ContextCompact.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
```

(and I *really* wish they had just used a `boolean` return value from `checkSelfPermission()`...)

Comment: My bad! But now the problem is that `locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider)` fails with `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid provider: null`. May it be due to the fact that the application is running on the emulator?

Comment: @user2989242: Possibly. Your low-power requirement will eliminate `GPS_PROVIDER` as an option. I rarely use the emulator, and so I do not know whether it emulates the network provider or not.

Comment: Yes, it was a problem of the emulator with a smartphone it works, but i've noticed that with `ACCURACY_COARSE` the last known location is always `null` while with `ACCURACY_FINE` i get the right location.